# Mongoose and data integrity

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How do I keep collections in sync during updates and deletions if I have the following schemas defined:

```
var RestaurantSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    menus: [{ 
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'Menu' 
    }]
});

var MenuSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    restaurant: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Restaurant',
        required: true
    }
});
```

I create a restaurant by doing the following:

```
Restaurant.create(restaurant, callback);
```

I create a menu and link it to a restaurant by doing the following:

```
Menu.create(menu, function(err, menu) {
    if (err) {
        callback(err, menu);
    }
    else {
        restaurantController.addMenu(menu.restaurant, menu._id,
            function(err, restaurant) {
                callback(err, menu);
            });
    }
});
```

First question, is there a better way to add menus to restaurants?

Second question, how do I keep the data in sync when I delete a menu or when I delete a restaurant?

Third question, how do I keep the data in sync across collections when I do an update that removes the id from the reference field. For example, if I do this:

```
Restaurant.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: _id }, { $unset.menus }, options, callback);
```

That will empty the menus array on the restaurant document, however, the menus document would still have the reference to the Restaurant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO `Menu` and `Restaurant` should have uni directional relationship. So, a `Restaurant` entity could reference `Menu` (if restaurant and menu needs to be 1-1) or a collection of Menus 1-n (breakfast, lunch, dinner etc..).

A `Menu` doesn't need to reference back the `Restaurant` since that might lead to circular reference problem.

Also, the data integrity might be screwed.
For example, what if a `Restaurant-A` references a `Menu-A`, but `Menu-A` references `Restaurant-B` ?

Regarding  your questions:
*First question, is there a better way to add menus to restaurants?*

1. Create a `Menu`, that should return you `_id`.
2. Add that reference to `Restaurant` `myRestaurant.menuId = _id`.
3. update restaurant.

   PS: You can flatten your structure by using promises instead.

*Second question, how do I keep the data in sync when I delete a menu or when I delete a restaurant?*

You are looking at 2 db operations (delete menu, remove the menu reference from Restaurant) which need to be run as a transaction. Checkout how you can do multi document transactions
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/

My above answer might suffice your third question.

*That will empty the menus array on the restaurant document, however, the menus document would still have the reference to the Restaurant.*

If you rewire your schema to be uni-directional, you wont have to worry about this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think a uni-directional schema is the way to go. I am new to all of this and from what I have been reading it seems like the recommended / best practice approach with MongoDB was to try and put the whole document in one record. But it does support document references and with Mongoose, there is the populate method. So I thought I should create the schema the way that I described because then I can simply use populate to build up the entire document since the related id is stored in an array property. What is the point of the populate method if you run into issues like this?

Comment: Maybe it's outside of the scope of the OP Question; but could you show an example of what you meant by "you can flatten your structure using promises instead," that is if you were referring to something other than async/await, on the controller level. I'm a newbie at Node/Mongoose as well.